# generate a meaningful random string using php

Tags: php, random

I would like to generate a random string with meaningful word

```
function randString($length, $charset='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'){
    $str = '';
    $count = strlen($charset);
    while ($length--) {
        $str .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $count-1)];
    }
    return $str;
}
```

I have used this function but it generate random which has not any meaning in dictionary.
Have you any idea or is it not possible.
Please let me know if you have any idea according or have better solution regarding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `meaningful` and `random` don't really go together well: if you need meaningful, then what about a random selection from a dictionary?

Comment: http://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/pseudo-language-generator/

Comment: You clearly need a vocabulary. So you will choose a random word inside the vocabulary.

Comment: @MarkBaker when we will refresh the page every time we need random meaningful word

Comment: @sonusindhu -- The first person to answer your question (Mark Baker), answered your question. Please re-read his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for a random alphanumeric string

```
function get_random_string($valid_chars, $length) {
    $random_string = '';

    //Count the number of chars in the valid chars string so we know how many choices we have
    $num_valid_chars = strlen($valid_chars);

    //Repeat the steps until we've created a string of the right length
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++) {
        //Pick a random number from 1 up to the number of valid chars
        $random_pick = mt_rand(1, $num_valid_chars);

        //Take the random character out of the string of valid chars
        //Subtract 1 from $random_pick because strings are indexed starting at 0, and we started picking at 1
        $random_char = $valid_chars[$random_pick-1];
        $random_string .= $random_char;
    }

    return $random_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Baker writes in the comments, "meaningful" and "random" are hard to bring together.

However, if you want to show a real word, from a given language, without someone being able to guess in advance what that word will be, you would do it as follows (in pseudocode, don't have time to write it out as PHP):

```
read list of unique words in language into wordList
generate random integer i, <= length of wordList
return word at position i in wordList
```

Consider using a [password dictionary](http://www.skullsecurity.org/wiki/index.php/Passwords) as the source of your wordlist.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of words from [ASPELL](http://aspell.net/) or http://sourceforge.net/projects/wordlist/, importing them into a db table and randomly select one by php :)

**Sample query:**

```
SELECT word FROM dictionary order by RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Good luck! I got an example code somewhere as I did the same two years ago.. Will take a look :)

Comment: I'm searching for it right now, when I find it I'll add it to my answer :)

Comment: Added sample query, can't find my `php` file right now. Hope this solves your question :)